# Primefaces Datatable row selection inside dialog

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, modal-dialog, seam

I am sorry for my English. I have a JBoss Seam Project and using primefaces in user interface.We have a dialog and inside a datatable. When i select a row im getting following error

```
ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000460: Error checking for a transaction
PersistenceException org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
```

I thought maybe this error about hibernate but When i tired a lot of way about this problem i couldnt done it But when i moved dialog to new xhtml page it was done.I want to use dialog for my project instead of new page.Where is my mistake following code?

```
<h:form id="vehicleForm">
<p:commandButton id="selectClientButton" value="Musteri Sec" actionListener="#{clientFacade.clientSearchClear()}" />
</h:form>
<h:form id="selectClientForm">
    <p:dialog widgetVar="selectClientDialog" resizable="true" draggable="true" modal="true"  header="Arac Satis">
            <h:panelGrid columns="4">

                            <h:outputText value="Adi" />
                            <h:outputText value="Soy Adı" />
                            <h:outputText value="TC/Vergi No." />
                            <h:outputText value="" />

                            <p:inputText value="#{clientFacade.client.name}" />
                            <p:inputText value="#{clientFacade.client.lastName}" />
                            <p:inputText value="#{clientFacade.client.taxNo}" />
                            <p:commandButton value="ARA" update=":selectClientForm:clientListDT" />
            </h:panelGrid>

                    <p:dataTable id="clientListDT" rows="10" value="#{clientFacade.clientList}" var="client"  >

                        <p:column style="width:3%" >

                            <p:commandLink id="test" actionListener="#{vehicleStockFacade.selectClient(client.clientId)}" ajax="false" >
                                <h:graphicImage value="#{icon.icon_select_mine_small}" rendered="#{client.isMyClient}"  title="#{msg.choose}" width="15" height="15"/>
                                <h:graphicImage value="#{icon.icon_select_not_mine_small}" rendered="#{!client.isMyClient}"  width="15" height="15" />
                            </p:commandLink>    

                        </p:column>

                        <p:column>
                            <f:facet name="header" >
                                <h:outputText value="#{msg.client_name}" />
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{client.name}" />
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="#{msg.client_lastname}" />
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{client.lastName}" />
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="#{msg.tax_no}" />
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{client.taxNo}" />
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="#{msg.cell_phone}" />
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{clientFacade.useMaskForPhone(client.mobilePhone)}" />
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="#{msg.town}" />
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{client.town}" />
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column>
                            <f:facet name="header" id="headerId" >
                                <h:outputText value="#{msg.address}" />
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{client.addressLine1}" />
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="#{msg.post_code}" />
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{client.postCode}" />
                        </p:column>

                    </p:dataTable>

            <f:facet name="footer">
                <p:commandButton value="Secimi Kaldir" action="#{vehicleStockFacade.removeClientFromVehicleStock()}" style="float:right;margin-bottom:5px" ajax="false" />              
            </f:facet>
        </p:dialog>

        </h:form>
```

Comment: I would guess that one of your DB queries is causing the exception which maybe invoked from your page template (would explain why its not thrown when you put it in a new page)....you need to post the full stacktrace, the answer is probably further up the trace

Comment: This line `PersistenceException org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection` is self-explanatory and does not match the question contents. You are supposed to dig in the database connection on Hibernate side.

Comment: The answer is in the stack trace. Please tell the versions and post the full stack trace.